# Basic proof about polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This is my attempt at proving the following statement: "Prove that every nonzero $f(x) \in F[x]$ has a unique monic associate in $F[x]$." Please note that $F$ denotes a field. Firstly I have attempted to prove that every nonzero $f(x)$ has a monic associate, and then the uniqueness of said monic associates.

Let $f(x) \in F[x]$. If $f(x)$ is monic we have that $f(x) = 1_{F}f(x)$ where $1_{F}$ denotes the identity element of $F$. Assume that $f(x)$ is not monic and denote the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ by $a$. Then since $F$ is a field, $a^{-1}$ exists and we can write $f(x)=aa^{-1}f(x)=a(a^{-1}f(x))$ by associativity. This proves the existence of monic associates.

For uniqueness, assume that $f(x)=bg(x)$ and $f(x)=cp(x)$ where $g(x),p(x) \in F[x]$ are monic. This implies that $bg(x)=cp(x)$. Comparing coefficients, in particular we must have that $b1_{F}=c1_{F}$ which implies $b=c$. This implies that $bg(x)=bp(x)$. Since every field is an integral domain, this implies $g(x)=p(x)$ which proves uniqueness.

I am not sure if my attempt is correct or not. Any feedback on my attempted proof would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the existence, you assume that $f$ is not monic in part of it. Where do you use this assumption? (Maybe you don't need two cases..)

Comment: Why does $a^{-1}$ exist? Another way to ask this is when does $a^{-1}$ not exist? Not that there is an issue here, but you do gloss it over.

Comment: Very similarly, you are correct in deducing $g =p$, but only because $b$ has a certain property. What is it?

Comment: @RghtHndSd $a^-{1}$ exists because $a$ is an element of $F$, which is a field, and every nonzero element in a field has a multiplicative inverse by definition. That was my thoughts behind it at least. Also, am I correct in assuming that the property you ascribe to $b$ is that it is nonzero? Because that follows from the definition of being two polynomials being associates, namely that $b$ must be a unit, and a unit is nonzero. I appreciate your feedback !

Comment: Exactly right. But why is $a$ nonzero? Without knowing these elements are nonzero, your proof would be incorrect. And while I suspected you knew why, it wasn't clear. In particular, it isn't clear where you use the hypothesis that $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: @RghtHndSd Thanks, thats a good point. I use it implicitly when I denote the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ by $a$, since by the assumption that $f(x)$ is nonzero, $f(x)$ has degree $0$ or higher, and $0_{F} \in F[x]$ does not have a degree by definition, so the leading coefficient in $f(x)$ is nonzero. Is this reasoning correct? It would probably be a good idea for me to be more explicit in my assumptions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that is precisely correct!